# Why is my Print Spooler Service dying and my print process hanging?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a C# process that prints an in memory pdf file using O2S.Components.PDFRender4NET, to different printers through out our company.  At seemingly random intervals (like once every other day), the print spooler service on the windows machine dies.  Also, the print process will hang indefinitely (at 0 cpu) at random intervals.

Any ideas as to how to determine what is causing the print spooler to die, or for my process to hang?  (I'm using the O2S code because I need to be able to rotate the paper and change the page scaling to none, which I can't figure out how to do in C# if I just send the pdf raw to the printer.  Is there something else I should be using?)

Comment: doesn't seem to be programming related, honestly. Check this out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistaprinting/thread/2634b214-64e7-4002-959e-5d11010b65c0

Comment: It only happens every 300+ or so printed documents.  It's also happening on two different Windows server 2008 boxes.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find the source of these errors... but I think it wasn't an issue with the print driver itself, but with the calling code spawning up too many threads.